# Flutter: json.decode change the order of elements

Tags: json, flutter, decode

I get this json String from a http-request:

```
{"163":[{"year":"2018","downloads":253}],"162":[{"year":"2018","downloads":525}]}
```

After json.decode my map look like:

```
{162: [{year: 2018, downloads: 525}], 163: [{year: 2018, downloads: 253}]}
```

How can i keep the sort order in my map?

thx

Answer (score -1):

It does not matter which order the map has. You can access the value of the property by calling `map['163']`

Furthermore I suggest to name json-properties in a valid way so that other programming languages can deserialize the json into classes. In your case 163 is in almost all programming language an invalid variable/property namy